# Can Artifactory be used to deploy archives such as zip, tar, tar.gz?

Tags: artifactory

I am trying to evaluate Artifactory for a particular usecase and I am looking for documentation which can support the usage of Artifactory for a repository of archives.

All I found was a documentation for deploying artifacts which have been archived in Artifactory's knowledgebase.

[How to deploy a bundle (how to deploy files from an archive)](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-deploy-a-bundle-how-to-deploy-files-from-an-archive/)

However, what I am looking for is whether Artifactory supports archives such as tars, zips etc.? Also, if there is any documentation around how I can manage these archives (concerns like best practices, tagging etc.)?

Comment: "archives" is really general and doesn't imply any particular use case, so unless you have something more specific in mind, it sounds like you're just looking for generic repositories. You can store any kinds of files in those.

Comment: @DarthFennec Could you point me to any documentation of Generic Repository in Artifactory?

Comment: All I could find is [this](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-SinglePackageType). I don't really think this is something that needs much documentation. It's just an unspecialized repository that can be used to store arbitrary artifacts.

Comment: @DarthFennec thanks for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Artifactory [Generic](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuring+Repositories#ConfiguringRepositories-GenericRepositories) repositories are intended for storing artifacts which are not managed by any type of package manager, this includes archives such as Zip, Tar and others.
If you are using a specific folder layout when deploying the artifacts, you can define a [custom repository layout](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Repository+Layouts) which allows to perform tasks such as automatic snapshot/integration versions cleanup.
Artifacts can be deployed to a generic repository using the UI or the [REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeployArtifact).
You can retrieves an archived resource from the specified archive destination using the [archive entry download](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArchiveEntryDownload) REST API.